# Replacing words in a body of text from array

Tags: c#

So I am trying to get my code to read all the text from a text box called txtBody for now, and to check them against listA, if any of the words from listA appear I would like to replace those words with the appropriate one from listB.  How can I do this?

For reference list A and B are from a CSV, ListA being column one and list B column 2, therefore listA[1] is the counter part of listB[1].

This is the code I have for the lists

```
  string body = txtBody.Text;
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("textwords.csv"));
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
        }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: How many words does the text entered inside the TextBox contain, 1, more ?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos the text box can contain any amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most simplest form, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
    body = body.Replace(listA[i], listB[i]);
```

However, if you have a word like `is` in `listA`, then something like `this` would be partially replaced.

**UPDATE**

If you want each word to be surrounded by spaces, you could add that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
{
    var word1 = string.Format(@"(\b){0}(\b)", listA[i]);
    var word2 = string.Format(@"$1{0}$2", listB[i]);

    body = Regex.Replace(body, word1, word2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

the regex will match the word, with spaces on either side, and replace it with the new word, keeping the spacing the same.

Comment: This doesn't handle a word at the beginning of the string (no space before it) or at the end (no space after it) or words followed by punctuation.

Comment: well the first solution does.  If OP provided more information I could give a better solution

Comment: right.. I think he using the space condition/example to suggest that you would have to handle using string.format in reqular expressions.

Comment: @Jonesy  what Kind of info are you after?

Comment: I've updated my answer for @juharr 's spacing concerns.

Comment: I would think `\b` would make more sense here.

Comment: @Jonesy now juaharr would like you to update your answer for [.]?[!]?[?]

Comment: @Jonesy how can you infer that he still wants to match if it is at the befinning of a new line?

Comment: I don't really have a lot to go off of, and OP isn't giving me any feedback.  I can't infer anything.  I'm going to leave this as is unless I get more context.

Comment: @Jonesy  I am about to try and implement it, But it looks ok to me,  The whole aspect of it is essentially its to read a message of any length and expand any text speak e.g. replace IMO with in my opinion or Lol with laugh out loud

Comment: @Jonesy  Hey, I there is a problem this code, When I run it, if there a word with the abbreviation in it, eg Lolly has lol in it, Is there a way to not replace words such as lolly with laugh out loud + ly and only replace the actual words such as lol or Rolfl etc

Comment: use `@"(\b){0}(\b)"` for word1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a regex.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
{
    Regex myRege = new Regex(listA[i]);

    body = Regex.Replace(body,listB[i];
}
```

If an entire word match is desired:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
{
    Regex myRege = new Regex(" " + listA[i] + " ");

    body = Regex.Replace(body,listB[i];
}
```

Comment: For a simple replace `string.Replace` would make more sense and performs better.  And this of course would substitute substrings, like if you are replacing the word "is" with "it" you would replace "this" with "thit".

Comment: @juharr depending on what the OP want, this could be easily modified? is it is an entire word match, just add a space before and a space after, or if you really want me to figure out the every possible use case without any more example from the OP, I guess I could...see edit.

Comment: That's just Jonesy's answer which has it's own set of issues.

Comment: @juharr In a sense, but if you look he posted the first half of his answer, I posted the Regex answer, and then he added it to his post.

Comment: But this does not gain anything from being a regex instead of a simple `string.Replace` (assuming the words in listA are not actually regular expressions).  Jonesy used the regex to get case insensitive replacement at least.

Comment: @CalvinSmith, he's just saying that it isn't a complete answer.. covering all possibilities.. he's looking for the full solution.. not the underline pattern.. you're correct in that this is the pattern.. but adding the full regular expressions would proven to be a better answer.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I understand exactly what he is saying. However what he is saying is very unhelpful. A person may or may not need more or less requirements. Maybe he doesnt want to match a period. Maybe he only wants it if it matchs an explanation mark. Maybe listA includes the punctuation he requires inside iteself. WIthout more information how on Earth can you possibly cover every use case.

Comment: @CalvinSmith, I agree.. just seeing a Reader.ReadLine on a csv file was enough for me to consider stating the pattern as the solution myself.. which both you and the other answerer did already.. so that's about as far as I would have gone with it.. but a comprehensive answer is optimal

Comment: @BrettCaswell Sure, but there is an accepted answer, a good answer, a comprehensive answer, and a holy crap regex lesson answer. The structure is in place to provide more comprehensive answers with just a little research by OP. His original question has been answered, and most answers spawn a new question or two.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq you can have sth like this:

```
string[] bodyWords = body.Split(' ');

// For each word contained inside body (s in bodyWords), if there is a match 
// in listA (i != 0), then get counterpart from listB (listB[i]), otherwise 
// leave it as it is. Use Join to reconstruct result string.
string result = string.Join(" ", (from s in bodyWords
                                  let i = listA.FindIndex(x => x == s)
                                  select i == -1 ? s : listB[i]).ToArray());
```

With this a input:

```
string body = "John Smith";

List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "John", "Two", "Smith", "Four", "Five" };
List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "Martin", "TwoB", "Jones", "FourB", "FiveB"};;
```

the above code yields as result: `"Martin Jones"`

Performance-wise this might not be the best possible solution, but it is always fun doing things in linq! :=)

Comment: Would this cover matching a name, like "John Smith" appearing in listA. My linq is not nearly as good as it should be yet, but it looks like splitting on spaces for your bodywords array might be a bad idea.

Comment: it's usually better to just leave body as a string, and use string.format over it in these situations.. lets not forget that strings are `char[]` and a culture.. there are some low-level performance considerations when comparing arr[] to arr[]. generally, if you're given a string method to perform a specific operation, use it..